# Is there any way to access some apps before I put in my password?

Tags: iphone, applications, password

I have a 4 digit passcode for my iphone, but there are some apps that I might use frequently that don't really need to be protected.  Is there a way to access those apps without entering my passcode every time?  An example of such an app would be the calculator or calendar apps, or even the Pandora app.

Any ideas?

Comment: you could always disable your passcode.

Answer (score 2):

No, although there are/were tweaks available on jailbroken devices that enabled locking specific apps with a(n unrelated) passcode.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Apple provides Siri (voice search, automation, calculator, and much more) and music control plus some notifications that respond to touch when on the lock screen.

No, in that you can't choose any app to actually run from the home screen before a passcode or slide to unlock action.

Back to the yes aspect of the answer, touch and Siri's access is very strictly limited and you don't get to use any apps in their full UI, but instead use Apple controls to automate things like changing volume, skipping to the next song, pausing and playing.

Similarly, when you use Siri to access things, you can generally input a new appointment and interact with data stored in an app as opposed to firing up the app's UI (in the case of calculator or other apps you ask about - like perhaps choosing a new playlist in pandora). Siri of course knows how to play music in the library, but not yet how to select a pandora playlist.

The prevailing idiom is to select specific apps that themselves have passcodes (banking apps, finance apps, secure work apps for medical data, etc…) and not worry about a device passcode or to just enter the device passcode to run any and all apps.

Comment: Hmm but how about blocking phone and messages and mail etc. I don't see much of your "prevailing idiom" The ones you mention needs stronger protection than a passcode and so musy have separate passwords/keys as teh Apple passcode is not strong enough

Comment: What do you mean by blocking? Having a second passcode lock or only having the passcode block those apps? Most businesses that worry about trivial passcodes use profiles to restrict a device to a complex passphrase instead of 4 numbers. Anyone can do this themselves by turning off **simple passcode** in Settings > General > Passcode Lock

Comment: I think what he means is that you can access certain functionality and certain data directly from your lock-screen through built-in features like Siri or the media controls of the lock-screen itself (the camera access also jumps into my mind). Although it might not answer what you asked directly, do consider Siri serves as a very powerful built in calculator through Wolfram Alpha, and you also have basic calendar, messages, reminders, (even Fandango and Opentable too), etc. functionality.

Comment: I meat if you did not use the passcode how would you block using phone, messages etc?

Comment: @mark Oh - well of course your phone isn't locked then. Often with BYOD situations, security is placed entirely on a separate log in or VPN credentials. But we're getting way off Andrew's basic question. Hopefully my edit makes this more clear.